# Upload videos to vimeo account using Java

Tags: java, api, upload, liferay-6, vimeo

I am developing a functionality in liferay 6.1.1 where I need to upload videos to a vimeo account.

I have gone through vimeo's site (http://developer.vimeo.com/) to get its API. But didn't get any API to make download and use. Can anybody guide me how I can use this API to upload videos on any vimeos's account?

Comment: Check this URL: http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload

Comment: @Nikhil you are right, but to get use this apis methods we will need it api(web service client)in our environment. How can get this?I am not getting any option to get it's api.

Comment: this is rest api and hence I don't think so vimeo is providing a client library in java. You can write a client class in java.

Comment: ok, but If we will create a java class , how can we access viemo's apis method directly?

Comment: I think it is a good idea if you look at a tutorial about rest. If you read something how rest work's then you have a good understanding how to communicate with vimeo.

Answer (score 1):

As documented on the [Vimeo API page](http://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#post) you need to send out a series of HTTP requests to their server. The easiest way to upload a file is to use Apache's HttpClient library.

In step 3 you actually do the upload, and how it is done you can [see on this page](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/05/21/jax-rs-resteasy-file-upload-httpclient-example/). It basically boils down to this:

**NOTE:** This code is only a general idea, it is untested and will most likely not compile.

```
/**
 * Uploads a file to Vimeo server.
 * @returns null if successful, error line otherwise.
 */
public String uploadVideoFile(String vimeoUrl, String ticketId, File file) throws Exception 
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(vimeoUrl);
    try {
        MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        multiPartEntity.addPart("ticket_id", new StringBody(ticketId));
        multiPartEntity.addPart("chunk_id", new StringBody("0"));

        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "application/octect-stream");
        multiPartEntity.addPart("file_data", fileBody);

        postRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(postRequest);

        if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            return response.getStatusLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
String status = uploadVideoFile("http://1.2.3.4/upload_multi",
            ticket, file);
```

You could also try using the streaming method as explained on the Vimeo page.